# Rails - Elasticsearch + rspec error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, rspec

I always end up with the following error, when i try to search imported records through rspec.

NoMethodError: undefined method `model_name' for [PROXY] Object:Elasticsearch::Model::Proxy::ClassMethodsProxy

method_missing, from proxy.rb

After some investigation, i found out that i can search through the records normally in development and test environment. But when i debug through one of the request specs (which invokes one of my actions involving elasticsearch methods) it doesn't go through and bamm, the same error.

Comment: config.before(:each) do
    [MyModel, MyOtherModel].each do |model|
      model.__elasticsearch__.create_index!(force: true)
    end
  end

Is this in your spec_helper.rb?

Comment: Yeah. Pretty much. Also some cleanup process for the database.